# When using fcm http v1, data messages do not arrive normally after about 20 times

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

**I wrote google translator. Please understand this part.**

hi.

There was a problem when upgrading the API version from FCM HTTP to FCM HTTP v1.

FCM HTTP v1 API request was made through POSTMAN.

Below is the sending message body.

```
{
    "message": {
        "topic": "this_is_test_topic",
        "data": {
            "body": "1234567890"
        },
        "android": {
            "priority": "high"
        }
    }
}
```

When I made the above request, IOS client received it normally even though it was sent once or twice per second.

However, the ANDROID client did not receive a message from FCM for a certain period of time after receiving the first 20 times.
The message could be transmitted once more after a certain time.

This was the same as the limitations of compact messages in the FCM documentation.
Link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options?hl=en#collapsible_throttling

However, I didn't put any data related to the miniature in the message I sent.

- If you make a request to the existing FCM HTTP with the same topic, data is received normally. Below is the corresponding code.

```
{
    "to": "this_is_test_topic",
    "data": {
        "body": "1234567890"
    }
}
```

- If the FCM HTTP v1 API is requested using the same topic and token instead of topic, data is received normally. Below is the corresponding code.

```
{
    "message": {
        "token": "asdkjasldjalksdjlk*******************",
        "data": {
            "body": "1234567890"
        },
        "android": {
            "priority": "high"
        }
    }
}
```

- all request response status code is 200

Comment: I haven't been able to fix this, and I've searched for how to fix it, but I didn't get any information.
please answer about my question.

Comment: Additionally, data containing only notifications are being received normally.